# autoLink not working

Tags: android, xml, autolink

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topic"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="#150a18"
        android:text="  +9177xxxxxx99"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp"

        />
```

`autoLink` not working. When I click on textview nothing happens.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

your number should be maximum 10 digit.
take a look at link bellow :
[Android:autoLink not working fully on my 4.4 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538201/androidautolink-not-working-fully-on-my-4-4-device)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it does not work properly. So, add below code also,

`TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a string in the resources area.

Support: [click here](http://www.something.com)

Maybe this will help